# Spring boot security using userDetailsService

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, spring-security

```
@Service
public class UserDetService implements UserDetailsService{
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUserName(userName);
    if(user == null){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(userName);
    }
    return new UserPrincipal(user);
}

}
```

SecConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
    return new UserDetService();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
}
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/hello").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")  
      .anyRequest().permitAll()
      .and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
        .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
      .and()
        .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout") 
       .and()
       .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
      .and()
        .csrf();
}


}
```

I was learning spring security and didn't find anyone to ask if I was correct and is this all to do to secure login authentication or have I missed something?

Also I got a confusion that I haven't written any queries to get username and password, how does the validation of username and password from user input and database work and where the validation occur ?

Thank you for such a helpful people around here

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write queries because if you are using `jpa` it will write the queries for you.

This line: `User user = userRepository.findByUserName(userName);`

Will use the repository to auto-generate the query to check if the supplied parameter returns anything and in your service

```
if(user == null){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(userName);
    }
```

will throw the error if the repository couldn't find the user.

Hope this answers your question.